# Using relative paths in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure how to correctly use relative paths in `nginx.conf`. It seems nginx uses different base dirs for different directives:

- `include`: This is relative to the config dir.
- `ssl_certificate`: This is relative to the config dir.
- `root`: This is relative to the prefix dir.
- `access_log`: This is relative to the prefix dir.
- ...

I don't have a full list for each directive. Is such a full list, or a suggestion about never using relative paths in `nginx.conf`, documented anywhere?